# Использование слота унаследованного класса [Qt]

Tags: qt, классы, наследование, сигналы-слоты

Пишу калькулятор, хочу сделать примерно следующую структуру (точнее она уже есть): класс `Calculator` и от него 2 наследника `UnaryOperation,` `BinaryOperation`, которые содержат свои слоты.

Вопрос следующий: каким образом в конструкторе класса `Calculator` подключить кнопки к слотам унаследованным классов?

Пробовал `public слоты` - не работает, пробовал делать слот виртуальным, тогда почему-то не могу создать объект класса Calculator. В общем перепробовал, наверное почти всё, вот, последняя надежда, выручайте. Заранее спасибо :)

Кнопки делал в ui-редакторе.

Пример коннекта в классе `Calculator`:

```
connect(ui->opPlus, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(MySlot()));
```

Вместо MySlot должен быть слот класса наследника.

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял, вы пытаетесь в конструкторе предка обратиться к слотам потомков. Это так не работает - предок не знает о своих потомках ничего, как следствие - предку неизвестно о наличии у потомков каких-либо слотов или функций.
Сделать то, что вы хотите, можно, только если вы передаете в конструктор `Calculator` указатели на объекты классов `UnaryOperation` и `BinaryOperation` и коннектите слоты, используя эти указатели. Но это неправильный путь. 
Более подробно я что-нибудь могу сказать, если увижу больше кода.

Опять же, если я правильно понял то, что вы хотите сделать - сделайте в предке сигналы `plusClicked` и `minusClicked`, законнектите их на соответсвующие сигналы кнопок, а затем в конструкторах потомков приконнектите сигналы предка к слотам потомков. Но, повторюсь, это выглядит очень топорно.